# Where is the API for "Invisible Ink" located?

Tags: imessage, ios10

I have secrets that need to be shared in my application, and would like to adopt the "Invisible Ink" feature that is new in iOS 10.

[image]
https://youtu.be/n5jXg_NNiCA?t=1h27m30s

Since I'm creating a greenfield application (version 1) I think this visual element of consistency is a good thing to include in my app.

Is the invisible ink UX available for developers?

Comment: in **Messages.framework**

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost, the invisible ink view is inside a private framework, and using private frameworks will cause your app to be rejected in the App Store reviewing process. Still, for the community's sake, here's your answer (I'm sorry I got it to you in Obj-C, I'll try and come back later to update it to Swift):

You need to go around using dlopen to load the ChatKit framework manually in your app:

```
dlopen("/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ChatKit.framework/ChatKit", RTLD_LAZY);
// or use RTLD_NOW if you need it loaded immediately
```

Then, instantiate a CKInvisibleInkImageEffectView using NSClassFromString:

```
id invisibleInk = [[NSClassFromString(@"CKInvisibleInkImageEffectView") alloc] initWithFrame: yourFrame];
[invisibleInk performSelector:@selector(setImage:) withObject: yourUIImage];
//You likely want to put the InvisibleInkView right over an UIImageView containing the very same image
```

That should do the trick for you. Remember to actually add the InvisibleInk view wherever you want using `yourView.addSubview(invisibleInk)`, and have fun.

Comment: setImage: which class metod call?

Comment: The setImage called via performSelector will call setImage from the CKInvisibleInkImageEffectView, passing `yourUIImage` as the image to be set.

Comment: in swift give me error. is there any way to do in swift?

Comment: Does anyone have an alternative for Invisible Ink that deosn't use  PrivateFrameworks?